# UI Virtualization using Polylines

Tags: c#, wpf, virtualization

I want to virtualize polylines. In my application up to seven polyline are showed and every polyline owns up to nine million points (only a fraction should be visible of course). Every polyline has a binding to a PointCollection. All polylines are inside a ScrollViewer control, that scrolling effects every one of them.
Now, I'm wondering how virtualization of a polyline is possible. I found an article about [Virtual Canvas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/03/08/performant-virtualized-wpf-canvas.aspx) by Chris Lovett from Microsoft but I'm not sure if it's working for my problem. Has anyone experience with something like that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation and decided to implement the virtualization as follows:
The data I was processing (the points of the polylines) was in real-world coordinates and had much more detail than could be shown on the display. The user should also be able to zoom in and see more detail.

1. Determine the distance between two (or three) pixels on the display in world coordinates. this allows me to decide whether or not I can remove a point of the polyline because it will end up at the same pixel location as a neighboring point.
2. Loop through the points:

   a. if the current point would be in the same location on the display as the previous point: skip it.

   b. if the current point and the two previous point are located on a straight line the previous point is not needed: remove the previous point, add the current (and add the next point (D) to prevent the rounding off of a slowly bending curve into a straight line).
3. Use the gathered points to draw the polyline

Depending on the data this helped me to reduce the original set back to approximately 30% but that is completely dependent on the data. No guarantees there ;)

When the user zoomed in I simply recalculated starting from step 1.

I added a lot of parameters to the algorithm so I could tweak and tune it to find the sweet spot between performance and quality of image. E.g., I added an epsilon that allowed me to specify how much distance between the line through A and C and point B was allowed to still consider point B to be on the line.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I see your point, but I'm afraid it's not working for my case because the polyline shouldn't visualize an object/image. It's visualizing medical data like ECG. So assume there is data from 24hours ECG emasurement and I already reduced the the dataset. You see I don't need to scroll in vertical direction simply in horizontal/time direction.  
I think the best way would be loading a subset of the entire dataset into the PointCollection and load further data on demand. The problem however is simulating the data would be completely there that scolling is possible...

Comment: Ah, yes you are correct my solution will not help you. In your case I would probably create a fixed set of points and manipulate them when scrolling. This way you will only change the coordinates but not add to or remove from the collection, which is a huge time saver.